# Left circle in badges are getting cropped a little bit

Tags: bug, design

As shown in the following image, the circles shown within the badges are getting cropped a little bit from right side. They don't appear as a complete circle:

[image: Badges]

I'm running Chrome version 52.0.2743.116 m on Windows 10.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome / Windows 10. Are you on a tablet there?

Comment: Same version here... Did you clear your cache?

Comment: no I just started from previous day

Comment: @Cerbrus it is also same for me badges section from top right tabs but are shown properly in firefox

Comment: hmmm, I also can't repro (also Chrome on Windows 10); I've even tried randomly zooming, but that's still fine... I'm on the exact same build as you 
"52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)"; very odd

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, it looks like setting the width property of the `.badge1, .badge2, .badge3` selector to `7` (up from `6`) fixes the bug.