# Can you clarify the meaning of 'obsolete' flags for comments?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, comment-flags, obsolete-flags

Some time ago, I flagged a few comments that I clearly considered obsolete. Surprisingly to me, four of them in a row were declined. The first flag was on [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333074/even-though-i-set-bounties-i-received-no-answers-what-is-wrong-with-my-questio#comment387041_333074):

> This is not a duplicate. He's asking very specifically what is wrong with these questions, which is a perfectly reasonable Meta question. These aren't a lot of fun to answer, perhaps, but it's not a duplicate of "what are my options".

The user who voted-to-close as duplicate retracted their vote after this comment was made. Therefore, I considered it obsolete [according to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging):

> obsolete — **a comment that is no longer relevant because it** has been addressed by an edit to the post, clarified by additional comments, or **contains no context because it references deleted content**

The [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333061/left-circle-in-badges-are-getting-cropped-a-little-bit#comment386917_333061) [three](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333061/left-circle-in-badges-are-getting-cropped-a-little-bit#comment386918_333061) [flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333061/left-circle-in-badges-are-getting-cropped-a-little-bit#comment386920_333061) were on a clarification discussion:

> no on chrome windows 10
>
> Chrome version?
>
> Version 52.0.2743.116 m

I flagged them after [editing the comments into the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/333061/revisions) (see the last sentence):

> I'm running Chrome version 52.0.2743.116 m on Windows 10.

Again, I considered the comments as obsolete [according to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging):

> obsolete — **a comment that is no longer relevant because it has been addressed by an edit to the post**, clarified by additional comments, or contains no context because it references deleted content

After the latter three flags were declined, I was so desperate that I raised a moderator flag (although it's clear to me that flags are not suitable for two-way discussions):

[image: Pending mod flag]

However, this flag hasn't been addressed since three and a half weeks now.

Where is my misunderstanding on the definition of obsolete comments?

Comment: Pending just means it's still in the queue to be looked at...

Comment: @Flexo Having a flag pending for three and a half weeks is pretty long though…

Comment: @Flexo: If this is, because the mods are still busy with other (earlier) flags, then it's fine for me. However, I reduced my flagging effort, because this issue is bugging me. I'm really looking for some guidance.

Comment: Most likely the decline was because whoever handled it didn't realise the edit had been made. Or they wanted to keep them until the issue was resolved since mso is somewhat different to the main site.  The main site has 1300+ flags in the queue. I can't speak for the other mods, but other than outright abuse I tend to rank mso flags lower priority than pretty much everything on main. (and am less inclined to intervene on meta generally anyway). I don't think you're doing anything wrong, but there are a lot of things at a much higher priority than obsolete comments on meta.

Comment: @Flexo: Should I better raise custom flags if it doesn't become clear at first glance that a comment is obsolete? However, this wouldn't really reduce your workload, right? Should I therefore better stop flagging on Meta at all?

Comment: @honk it would actually help if *more* people flagged comments on meta. If  3 or 6 (can't remember the exact number) of flags are raised on a comment, it will be deleted automatically.

Comment: @Flexo: _Or they wanted to keep them until the issue was resolved:_ Does this really warrant three declines? I fear that such a decision could quickly get me banned...

Comment: @Glorfindel: That's fine, but how could I influence that without annoying anyone?

Comment: @Glorfindel isn't that limited to only comments that contain certain trigger words?

Comment: @rene could be - can't find the reference Q&A on mobile

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Thanks for your edit. I very much appreciate your continuous effort to copy edit posts!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think I can see what happened with these.

The first flag on Cody Gray's comment was declined because, while the duplicate vote was removed, Cody's comment still can serve a useful purpose in indicating why future voters shouldn't vote to close as a duplicate. We often leave comments like this alone when flagged if we think they'll be useful to future readers.

The other three were handled right as you were editing, by a staff member who was commenting on the question just as you were flagging. I bet those flags appeared to him as he was commenting, and would have required a page refresh to see your edits. It probably was a timing quirk that he didn't see the edits and thus didn't see why these were obsolete.

Declined comment flags don't lead to flag bans, so don't worry about that.

For your custom flag, custom flags are completely unsorted at present and we only have limited tools for triaging them. Even if we did, we have a lot of more time-sensitive or easier things to check into, so flags about declined comment flags would probably be passed over as we're working on other things. We'd eventually get to it, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the "other three" flags, can you please also comment on the suggestion in @rene's answer: Would it be better to raise custom flags if it's not fully obvious that a comment is obsolete? Or would that be a bad idea (see my comment on rene's answer)?

Comment: "Declined comment flags don't lead to flag bans, so don't worry about that." However, it does lead to the comment flags which should had led to moderator action being ignored and obsolete comments remaining. While leaving the useless comments wouldn't cause an immediate panic-level problem as users can inspect closer to identify that it is not helpful, it definitely wastes a lot of time on future readers. The moral of the story is to review your flags often and flag the incorrectly declined ones again, to alert the moderators into taking appropriate action.

Comment: @Unihedron but use a custom flag in that case, yes /no? I doubt if it is appreciated when you keep re-flagging a comment as obsolete while the mods miss the (subtle) reason it is so.

Comment: @honk - If it isn't immediately apparent why something is obsolete, a custom comment flag that explains "this was edited into the answer, and is no longer relevant", etc. can definitely be helpful. Custom comment flags are sorted into a different bucket than custom post flags, and tend to be a little easier to work through.

Comment: @BradLarson: Thank you; your comment is some important guidance for me. Would you dare to put that into your answer? Or might other mods see this matter differently?

Comment: Edits don't require a page refresh to see.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is frustrating but you have to keep in mind that moderators don't have much context when they handle a flag (yes, that is sub-optimal) and given the workload they might not take the time to create that context, specially on comments.

When you use one of the pre-baked flags, first make sure you use the flag that best fits the reason why it should be removed. You can ask yourself: If this comment is the only thing the mod sees, will they understand it is *rude*,
 <s>*obsolete*, *not constructive*</s> *no longer needed*, assuming you choose the right flag. If you expect that it might not be immediately clear from the comment alone, you better use a custom flag and re-create the context for them.

For example: if I edit a comment into an post, I raise a custom flag to explain that the comment is added in the post, so the comment is obsolete. I did have success with pre-canned obsolete flags on *Thanks, this helped* comments on answers that were marked accepted.

Seeing that one of your flags is on an upvoted comment in  which case I would always fallback to the custom flag, explaining why it needs to deleted, despite the upvotes. Specially on meta where moderators are much less inclined to remove upvoted comments as they might convey an opinion and removing those might be interpreted as silencing those opinions.

I do realize using custom flags makes our workflow a bit more intensive but I expect it does help the mod team to make the right call, especially if you're concerned in getting your flags marked helpful. Do not worry too much, mistakes do happen and declined comment flags have no impact on your ability to flag.

Comment: I don't mind spending more effort in raising custom flags, if this helps the mods to do their job. I just was not aware that this is appreciated in case a standard flag would also fit. I feared that such flags might be declined with the message: _"Please use standard close votes or flags for this."_ Did this ever happen to you?

Comment: That is a good point @honk but I don't recall any meta post about that decline reason or in my own history for that matter. But I'm eager to learn their view on it.

Comment: Ok, then let's hope that a few mods chime in, even if they are busy...

Comment: If raising the obsolete flag is not sufficient context, then there is a problem with the obsolete flag that needs to be fixed. Raising a custom flag that's redundant with the obsolete flag either means that the obsolete flag should be removed, or additional context should be shown with it automatically.

Comment: This is all wrong, I think. It's literally impossible for a comment to be *obsolete* for reasons that don't involve context. A "thanks, this helped" comment isn't obsolete, it's "too chatty" or "not constructive"; *obsolete* flags are *explicitly for* comments that have been *addressed*, which is based upon context by definition. Either mods need to look at context when they receive such flags, or the flag should be removed. Personally I've found that mods *do* handle my obsolete flags sensibly; I think the OP in this case was just unluckily the victim of some mod mistakes (which happen).

Comment: @MarkAmery thanks, I have edited it to make it even more wrong. See if that fits better.

Comment: @MarkAmery When I believe that the reason (context) for an obsolete flag may not be immediately obvious, I raise a custom flag that begins with "Obsolete -" and follows with a short description of the reason. I do this because I know that the mods are *exceptionally busy*. My feeling is that the mod can then quickly confirm the rationale that I supplied with my custom flag and take the appropriate action (accept or decline). I have had very good success with this approach.

Comment: @rene: Thank you for refining your answer, but the beginning of your second paragraph now overshoots a bit, even if it is correct. For example: _"Flagging an obsolete comment as too chatty"_ - This isn't anything I suggested. I am aware that I have to use the proper flags. My problem is that those flags might not convey sufficient context.

Comment: @honk I have removed that and decided that I can't please everyone.

Comment: @rene: I know that problem quite well ;) But at least I'm pleased now. Thanks again for you answer!