# Badge class icons are cropped in the profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

I noticed that the bronze/silver/gold badge icons are being cropped from the right in the activity tab of the profile:

[image: evidence]

The problem seems a bit similar to [this bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333061/left-circle-in-badges-are-getting-cropped-a-little-bit) which was not reproducible. I'm using Firefox 45.9.0 on Debian, with no recent changes in Firefox nor any userscripts that I know of.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find that dupe. I'll keep this around because the dupe target doesn't address the profile so this might be a helpful signpost.

Comment: Should I add the profile badges to my post?

Comment: @Xufox I guess it can't hurt :)